# express-typescript-react: 404 (not found) frontend bundle file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, webpack

I am making a full stack application, with Express(written in Typescript) and React. I am using webpack to bundle both backend and frontend.

I have two separate configs for webpack. One for frontend and the other one for backend.

Frontend config (`webpack-fe.config.js`)

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CleanWebpack = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

const FRONTENDSRC = path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend/src');

module.exports = {
  target: 'web',
  // @babel/polyfill is needed to use modern js functionalities in old browsers.
  entry: ['@babel/polyfill', path.resolve(FRONTENDSRC, 'index.js')],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle-fe.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx$|.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            // To process async functions.
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator']
          }
        },
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$|.sass/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', FRONTENDSRC],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.css', '.scss']
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(FRONTENDSRC, 'index.html')
    }),
    new CleanWebpack(['./dist/bundle-be.js', './dist/index.html'])
  ],
  watch: true,
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 9000
  }
};
```

Backend config (`webpack-be.config.js`)

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpack = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

const projectDir = 'string value used to define path';

module.exports = {
  context: projectDir,
  target: 'node',
  // @babel/polyfill is needed to use modern js functionalities in old browsers.
  entry: [
    '@babel/polyfill',
    path.join(projectDir, 'backend', 'src', 'index.ts')
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(projectDir, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle-be.js',
    publicPath: path.join(projectDir, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            // To process async functions.
            plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-async-to-generator']
          }
        },
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      },
      {
        test: /.ts$/,
        loaders: ['ts-loader'],
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ['node_modules', path.join(projectDir, 'backend', 'src')],
    extensions: ['.js', 'web.js', 'webpack.js', '.ts', '.tsx']
  },
  plugins: [new CleanWebpack([path.join(projectDir, 'dist', 'bundle-be.js')])],
  watch: true,
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map'
};
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
const feConfig = require('./webpack-fe.config');
const beConfig = require('./webpack-be.config');

module.exports = [feConfig, beConfig];
```

Here is the code for Server Initialization (`index.ts`)

```
import http from 'http';
import debug from 'debug';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackDevMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';

import App from './server';

const config = require('../../webpack-be.config.js');
const compiler = webpack(config);
debug('ts-express:server');

class InitServer {
  private port: number | boolean | string;
  private server: any;

  constructor() {
    this.port = this.normalizePort(process.env.port || 7000);
    App.set('port', this.port);
    App.use(
      webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
        publicPath: config.output.publicPath
      })
    );
    this.server = http.createServer(App);
    this.server.listen(this.port);
    this.server.on('error', this.onError);
    this.server.on('listening', this.onListening);
  }

  private normalizePort = (val: number | string): number | string | boolean => {
    let port: number = typeof val === 'string' ? parseInt(val, 10) : val;
    if (isNaN(port)) return val;
    else if (port >= 0) return port;
    else return false;
  };

  private onError = (error: NodeJS.ErrnoException): void => {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') throw error;
    let bind =
      typeof this.port === 'string' ? 'Pipe ' + this.port : 'Port ' + this.port;
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'EACCES':
        console.error(`${bind} requires elevated privileges`);
        process.exit(1);
        break;
      case 'EADDRINUSE':
        console.error(`${bind} is already in use`);
        process.exit(1);
        break;
      default:
        throw error;
    }
  };

  private onListening = (): void => {
    console.log(`listening on ${this.port}`);
    let addr = this.server.address();
    let bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? `pipe ${addr}` : `port ${addr.port}`;
    debug(`Listening on ${bind}`);
  };
}

new InitServer();
```

Here is the server config file(`server.ts`)

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import path from 'path';
import { projectDir } from './shared/constants';

class App {
  public express: express.Application;

  constructor() {
    this.express = express();
    this.middleware();
    this.routes();
  }
  private middleware(): void {
    this.express.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
      next();
    });
    this.express.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  }
  private routes(): void {
    this.express.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(projectDir, 'dist', 'index.html'));
    });
  }
}
export default new App().express;
```

I use the following commands in the npm scripts:

```
"bundle": "webpack",
"serve": "node dist/bundle-be.js"
```

When I start the server, it serves my `index.html` file from the dist folder, but it gives me a 404 error for `bundle-fe.js`. I have checked that `bundle-fe.js` is generated in the dist folder. So why does it give me a 404 for `bundle-fe.js` ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Found it, I had to change the config file that I was using in `index.ts` file.

```
const config = require('../../webpack-fe.config.js'); // instead of webpack-be.config.js
```

Lol ^^ !!